# How can I minimise my Bash shell prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal, prompt

Currently the terminal prompt looks like this:

```
[karlis@karlis-desktop current_folder]$
```

How can I *minimize* the prompt, so that it only shows $ or # without extra info in square brackets?

I checked the preferences for the default Gnome-Terminal and Terminator - there are no settings for this. It is pretty hard to use terminal when working in directories with long names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Modify `$PS1`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/).

Comment: The only thing I would recommend is to use `tput` instead of the raw escape sequences. You can do fancier things that way as well.